# VHDL book example

Tags: vhdl

I am just starting to learn VHDL and thought I would go threw the book examples and put them into the compiler and then attach a constraints file and try running it on the CPLD board that I got for the class. Problem being that once all the code is done and the compiler finishes and I program it onto the board I am getting no response from the board from my input.

I am now wondering if I made a mistake in the VHDL code that was copped from the book, I am not finding any difference from the book but I was hopping another with more experience could look it over and point out if I made a mistake.

```
--Truth Table page 193

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity TruthTable is
    Port (
        a,b,c : in bit;
        y     : out bit);
end TruthTable;

architecture truth of TruthTable is
    Signal in_bits : Bit_vector (2 downto 0);
begin
    in_bits <= a & b & c;
        with in_bits select
        y    <= '0' when "000",
                    '0' when "001",
                    '0' when "010",
                    '1' when "011",
                    '1' when "100",
                    '0' when "101",
                    '1' when "110",
                    '1' when "111";                 

end truth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. I would guess the problem resides in the mapping between the VHDL pins a, b, c and d and the board's CPLD's pinout.

I advise you to revise the synthesis and program processes, and to double-check your pin mapping.